# Attempting to get logo placed above Navbar items in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

How can I center the Navbar.Brand on top of the Navbar.Items.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to StackOverflow and new to React.js.

I've tried to edit the orientation with this through the Navbar styling in my css file but that has not been much help to me either.

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nh4E.png)

[This is the orientation that Im looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0vn1.png)

'''

```
function NavBar() {
  const [expand, updateExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [navColour, updateNavbar] = useState(false);

  function scrollHandler() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 20) {
      updateNavbar(true);
    } else {
      updateNavbar(false);
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

  return (
    <Navbar
      expanded={expand}
      fixed="top"
      expand="md"
      className={navColour ? "sticky" : "navbar"}
    >
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/" className="d-flex">
           <img src={logo} className="img-fluid logo" alt="brand" />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle
          aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"
          onClick={() => {
            updateExpanded(expand ? false : "expanded");
          }}
        >
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </Navbar.Toggle>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mx-auto" defaultActiveKey="#home">
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" onClick={() => updateExpanded(false)}>
                <AiOutlineHome style={{ marginBottom: "2px" }} /> Home
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>

            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link
                as={Link}
                to="/about"
                onClick={() => updateExpanded(false)}
              >
                <AiTwotoneEye style={{ marginBottom: "2px" }} /> The Story
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>

            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link
                as={Link}
                to="/project"
                onClick={() => updateExpanded(false)}
              >
                <FaFlask
                  style={{ marginBottom: "2px" }}
                />{" "}
                The Lab
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>

            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link
                href="placeholder.com"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noreferrer"
              >
                <AiOutlineTrophy style={{ marginBottom: "2px" }} />  How To Join
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link
                href="placeholder.com"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noreferrer"
              >
                <FaDiceFive style={{ marginBottom: "2px" }} /> More
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

'''

Comment: Can you link a codesandbox here?

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox? Just apply `flex-direction: row`, that is if your `Container` implementation accepts classes.